# How to fill null value in object attributes in feature engineering?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, kaggle, sklearn-pandas

I have look into the fill null method on Kaggle in feature engineering.
Some players fill the NA with another object value.

For example, there are 'Male', 'Female' and NA values in sex column. The method is fill NA with another object value, like, 'Middle'. And after that, it treats the sex attribute without any null and pandas will not find null.

I want to know the method has really good impact on machine learning model's performance or a good feature engineering?
Besides that, is there any other good way to fill NA after no knowledgeable discovery in the data set?

Comment: Some additional NA imputation techniques are discussed in this blog: https://trainindata.medium.com/feature-engineering-for-machine-learning-a-comprehensive-overview-a7ad04c896f8 and can be implemented with the SimpleImputer from sklearn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) or with the open source Python package Feature-engine: https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imputation/index.html

Answer (score 2):

First, it depends if your model can manages NA (like xgboost).
Second, are the dropouts explanatory of a behavior (like a depressed man is more likely to skip a task)

There is a **whole literature** about this questions. The main ways to do are:

1. Just drop the rows
2. Fill the missing data with replacements (the median, the most seen value...)
3. Fill the missing data and add some error to it

So here, you can either leave it NA and use xgboost, drop the uncomplete rows or put the most frequent value between male and female

A few recommendations if you wan to go further :

1. Try to understand why the datas are missing
2. Perform sensitivity analysis of the solution you chose

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on your data.
But still there are few things you can do and check if they work.

1.If there are few missing values compared to number of rows,its better to drop them.

2.If there are large missing values,make a feature "IsMissing"(1 for NULL 0 for others).Sometimes it works great.

3.If you have lot of data and somehow you figured out that the feature is really important,you can train a model to predict Male/Female using your train data.Then use the rows of Null values as test data to predict their value(Male/Female).

Its all about creativity and logic.Every hypothesis you make doesn't work great, as you can see the last method i described above assumes that the NULL values can only have two values(M/F),which in reality may not be the case.

So,play around with different tactics and see what works great for your data.

Hope it helps!!